# How to use JWT authentication with a per user model in pouchdb/couchdb?

Tags: couchdb

I want to let people sign in with google. At that point, they should connect to a database with their id, if the database doesn't exist, it should be created. This should be the only way to create databases.

Sign in with google works with a JWT token.

So, the logic I need is something like: Only someone with a token signed by google, where the id is x, should be able to connect to the database with the name x.